# Extra parameter is coming with a POST

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

My model is this a Movie class with this metadata:

```
    [MetadataType(typeof(MovieMetadata))]
    public partial class Movie
    {

    }

    class MovieMetadata
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Title is required")]]
        [StringLength(70, ErrorMessage = "Title must have a lenght less than 70")]
        public string title { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "The realese date of the movie is required")]
        public DateTime releaseDate { get; set; }

        public string storyline { get; set; }

        public Binary poster { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public Binary trailer { get; set; }
    }
```

My Create View has this code inside:

```
     @using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "createForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="gallMemberBox">

        <div class="rightFormContent">

            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.title)

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.title)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.title)
            </div>

            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.releaseDate)

                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.releaseDate)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.releaseDate)
            </div>

            <div>
                @Html.Label("Poster")

                <input name="poster" value="C:" id="poster" type="file" />
            </div>

            <div>
                @Html.Label("Trailer")

                @*  @Html.TextBox("trailer", "", new { type = "file", id="trailer" })*@
                <input name="trailer" value="" id="trailer" type="file" />
            </div>

            <div>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.storyline)

                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.storyline, new{id="storyline"})
            </div>

            <div>
                @Html.Label("Directors")
                <select class="chosen-select" multiple="" data-placeholder="Select directors">
                    @for(int i = 0; i < directors.Count; i ++)
                    {
                        <option value="@i">@directors[i].name</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>

            <div>
                @Html.Label("Actors")
                <select class="chosen-select" multiple="" data-placeholder="Select actors of the Screen">
                    @for(int i = 0; i < actors.Count; i ++)
                    {
                        <option value="@i">@actors[i].name</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>

            <div>
                @Html.Label("Writers")
                <select class="chosen-select" multiple="" data-placeholder="Select writers of the Film">
                    @for(int i = 0; i < writers.Count; i ++)
                    {
                        <option value="@i">@writers[i].name</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>

            <input type="submit" value="Create" />

        </div>
}
```

I just filled title and releaseDate and click on submit(Create), after that in my ModelState I have three parameters, title, releaseDate and storyline(I never put some value on this one, and the value is an empty string. On the others fields I never put a value and they do not come with that POST. Why? And how to fix this?

```
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "poster, trailer")]Movie movie, HttpPostedFileBase poster, HttpPostedFileBase trailer)
    {
```

[image]

Comment: Just for the experiment, try to change input for storyline field from @Html.TextAreaFor to @Html.EditorFor(model => model.storyline).

Answer (score 0):

Your field storyline will already be available by the id and name "storyline as this is created like by MVC.

Remove the "id" part, or use "@id = ...".

Comment: I am using this  @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.storyline) but still I am receiving storyline like an empty string in my ModelState

Answer (score 0):

You can write:

```
<div>
      Storyline
      @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.storyline)
</div>
```

Comment: I am using this  @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.storyline) but still I am receiving storyline like an empty string in my ModelState